# How to use complex query in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to do a query inside my model and call it in my controller, but for some reason I get some errors. Here is my model:

```
class Room extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Room';
var $displayField = 'title';
var $actsAs = array('Containable');

function select($qwe){
    $results = $this->Room->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE qwe= ".$qwe." ");
}
```

In this case, I get `Undefined property: Room::$room`. In the controller I have:

```
...
function success(){
    $qwe = "testing"
$this->set('get', $this->Room->select($qwe));    
}
}
```

Any idea about what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling within a Model so

```
    $results = $this->Room->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE qwe= ".$qwe." ");
```

should be

```
    $results = $this->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE qwe= ".$qwe." ");
```

because `query()` is a method of Class Model which is the parent class of every other Model, Model Room has no property Room that's why causing the error. If you would call this function via controller then you use `$this->ModelName->method()`

Your function `select` isn't returning anything, you should change it to

```
   function select($qwe){
       $results = $this->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE qwe= ".$qwe." ");
       return $results;
   }
```

Comment: great, thanks, one more thing if i may... in the view i use `<?php foreach ($get as $data):?>....` and i get `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. what u think the problem might be?